# Sci-fi kids' cartoon with with one episode where two moons suddenly appeared in the sky and it turned out to be a paper facsimile

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I'm looking for a kids' sci-fi cartoon from the '90s-2000s. It had a dual protagonist cast, one girl and one boy. They looked like the kids from the *[StarFlyers](https://archive.org/details/starflyers00lear)* CD-ROM games.

In one episode of the show, there suddenly appeared two moons in the sky and it turned out to be a paper facsimile.

If anyone knows this show, can they please tell me the title? Because this has been driving me up the wall for a few years now.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you tell us anything more about the basic premise of the show? Like, what kind of location/world was the story set in? Did the boy and girl have notable relatives or friends? Did they go to school? Were there any other notable characters, such as an antagonist? And what sort of sci-fi elements were in the show, specifically?

Comment: _You say it's only a paper moon
/ Sailing over a cardboard sea
 / But it wouldn't be make believe if you believed in me..._